# GCP Firewall rules don't seem to work from outside of google network

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, firewall

When I create a new inbound FW rule on port 8000 (or any other "non-default" port) I can reach it (external IP) from cloud shell, or other GCP VMs (that are running in a different GCP account / project), but I CAN'T reach it from outside of Google Network.

I have also tried opening all inbound ports, but still same result

vm describe below:

```
{
    "canIpForward": false,
    "cpuPlatform": "Intel Broadwell",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-06-24T04:16:32.565-07:00",
    "deletionProtection": false,
    "id": "6964106614441578464",
    "kind": "compute#instance",
    "labelFingerprint": "42WmSpB8rSM=",
    "machineType": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/spl-987/zones/asia-southeast1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1",
    "metadata": {
        "fingerprint": "soQGNew9LaQ=",
        "kind": "compute#metadata"
    },
    "name": "spl-001",
    "networkInterfaces": [
        {
            "accessConfigs": [
                {
                    "kind": "compute#accessConfig",
                    "name": "external-nat",
                    "natIP": "35.198.214.79",
                    "networkTier": "PREMIUM",
                    "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"
                }
            ],
            "fingerprint": "lgjIezyxW4o=",
            "kind": "compute#networkInterface",
            "name": "nic0",
            "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/spl-987/global/networks/default",
            "networkIP": "10.148.0.3",
            "subnetwork": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/spl-987/regions/asia-southeast1/subnetworks/default"
        }
    ],
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/spl-987/zones/asia-southeast1-a/instances/spl-001",
    "serviceAccounts": [
        {
            "email": "11111111111-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
            "scopes": [
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "startRestricted": false,
    "status": "RUNNING",
    "tags": {
        "fingerprint": "5PuyOqG8VDY=",
        "items": [
            "http-server",
            "https-server",
            "splunk"
        ]
    },
    "zone": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/spl-987/zones/asia-southeast1-a"
}
```

firewall rule describe bellow:

```
{
  "allowed": [
    {
      "IPProtocol": "tcp",
      "ports": [
        "8000"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "creationTimestamp": "2019-06-24T04:49:59.685-07:00",
  "description": "",
  "direction": "INGRESS",
  "disabled": false,
  "id": "6274426826248750600",
  "kind": "compute#firewall",
  "logConfig": {
    "enable": true
  },
  "name": "allow-splunk",
  "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/spl-987/global/networks/default",
  "priority": 100,
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/spl-987/global/firewalls/allow-splunk",
  "sourceRanges": [
    "0.0.0.0/0"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your question seems to say you "can" reach the opened firewall port ... is that a typo, did you mean "can't".  Are there any log messages written to Stackdriver?  Are there other conflicting rules that have higher priority?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, edited my question. The problem is that i can reach it within GCP network, but not outside of it.

Comment: If it were me, I'd create a firewall rule that denys everything and switch on logging for that.  Next I'd create the rule that allows me to access 8000 and ALSO switch on logging for that.  Then I'd run a connection test.  and examine the stackdriver logs to see what hit and what didn't hit.